# Exporting a dataset from google cloud datalab to google colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, data-mining

I have created a dataset in my Google Cloud data lab, and I would like to continue the processes on it in Google Colab (using Python). I do not know how should I export my dataset to Google Colab (or Jupyter). Would you please help me with it?

Here is my dataset in Google Datalab:

```
%sql --module afewrecords
Select pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime, pickup_longitude,
pickup_latitude, dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude, passenger_count,
trip_distance, tolls_amount, fare_amount, total_amount
 
From [nyc-tlc:yellow.trips] LIMIT 10

trips = bq.Query(afewrecords).to_dataframe()
trips
```

I want trips in Google Colab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you accessing data from BigQuery within your Datalab Notebook instance?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes yes

Answer (score 0):

In order to read your BigQuery data into a DataFrame within your Colab instance, you need to,

1. Create a Project with [Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager), if you do not have one;
2. [Enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project?visit_id=637510546519649425-1259817262&rd=1#enable-billing) for the project;
3. Enable the BigQuery API, so you can interact with BigQuery;

After these steps, you can use [this snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/bigquery.ipynb#scrollTo=nFF9Wz1CAyVI) from the documentation. Notice that `from google.colab import auth auth.authenticate_user()` authenticate your request to access BigQuery. Also, you will be using the `pd.io.gbq.read_gbq()` to write your query.